# Why isn't Queue.qsize accurate?

Tags: python, queue

According to the [Python 2.7](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue.qsize) docs, `Queue.qsize` isn't dependable, and `help(Queue.Queue.qsize)` says that it isn't reliable.  Is there a particular implementation issue I am not aware of?

P.S.  I am aware that `Queue.Queue.qsize` uses mutexes, and that the size of the `Queue` may change between when I call the method and when I get the result, but for single-threaded applications, are `Queue`s safe?

Message from `help(Queue.Queue.qsize)`:

```
>>> help(Queue.Queue.qsize)
Help on method qsize in module Queue:

qsize(self) unbound Queue.Queue method
    Return the approximate size of the queue (not reliable!).

>>>
```

Comment: You may want to take a look at [the source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/Queue.py).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Queue.Queue.qsize` works fine in a single-threaded application (and even in a multi-threaded application for many applications of its purpose). You simply can't use it to reliably determine whether a call to `put` or `get` will block.

Note that if you don't need concurrency, [`collections.deque`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) is faster than `Queue.Queue`. Or, if performance isn't critical, you could go the simple route and just use regular lists.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "_you don't need concurrency_", the documentation on deque says: "_Deques support thread-safe, memory efficient appends and pops..._". Can you clarify?